# Spring installation with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring

I have downloaded and installed Spring STS for Eclipse...
But when I've Created a Spring Project I can't to

`import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;`

So I tried to add library like spring.jar but I couldn't find this jar.(properties-->java build path-->libraries)
What's wrong with this setting? Or my installation is not ended?

Answer (score 1):

Spring STS is only a Eclipse plugin which helps the developer managing spring beans. It is not mandatory for developing a spring-based application.

So your second approach was the right one to add the spring library. You can download spring here: [Spring Downloads](http://www.springsource.org/download) and then add it as a library to your project.

But serious... I would encourage you to do a tutorial first: http://www.springsource.org/tutorials

Comment: I have to reinstall the Eclipse plugin after Spring frmwk ?? or not ?

Comment: You don't have to install any plugin just add the right spring jar to your build path. This is a very basic thing... maybe you should learn how to use libraries before starting using spring.

Comment: -1. These tutorials haven't any helpful information on the question of Spring installation. And it is impossible to try things without installation.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins does not includes library of spring.

Plugin is only to manage the reference of configuration in your project build in eclipse.
Libraries are actual jar file which is required at compile as well as run time.

If you skip the plugin installation then your code will work if your configuration is correct
But if you skip spring library installation or download then your code will not compile of run.

Please go through step by step tutorial by following these tutorial

[Spring Step By Step Tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html)